# How to mark specific rows in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to mark all the rows of this table:

AB-Table:
[image: AB-Table]

To this:
[image: Final result]

I want to do it via conditions (rules).

How can I do it? (if possible), Or - which rule I should write?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select the range.
- Home -> Conditional Formatting -> New Rule -> Use a formula to determine which cells to format.
- Type the formula `=$F1="A"`.
- Click <kbd>Format</kbd>. Set it background to blue.
- Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

[image]

- Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

[image]

- Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

This will be the result:

[image]

Comment: What is the "$" means? That the F row is const but the number is can be change? (for all the selection area). Thank you!!

Comment: @HebUser You are correct. The columns won't change but the rows will. See [Mixed reference](https://exceljet.net/glossary/mixed-reference).